# MysqlDump Return a Empty database backup file

Tags: php

I use this code for download a backup of MySql database but it download a empty file.
Please also guide for restore this backup.

```
<?php
//connect to database
include'connect.php';
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';
$command = "mysqldump -h$hostname -u$username -p$password $dbname > $backupFile";
system($command);
?>
```

Comment: Does it work when you type in this command manually?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `system` with `echo` to show the generated command, and execute it on the command line manually. Errors are usually shown on STDERR, which isn't caught by the `system` call, and if you get an empty output that means it couldn't output anything. Fix the error and then fix your code. I'd also use `passthru` instead of `system`.

To restore the backup afterwards use (from the commandline):

```
mysql -u<user> -p <database> < myfile.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

Your variables are sticked to the options. Try to change this:

```
$command = "mysqldump -h$hostname -u$username -p$password $dbname > $backupFile";
```

To this:

```
$command = "mysqldump -h $hostname -u $username -p $password $dbname > $backupFile";
```

Comment: Actually when I login, I usually type `mysql -uroot -p`, should work regardless :)

Comment: No, his syntax is right. Specifically if there's whitespace between `-p` and the password the tool will ask for a password instead of using it, and use the password as the catalog name. All MySQL tools read `-p` as shorthand for `--password=`, including the `=` so it's fine to attach them.